# Time series as cross-sectional data

Tags: r, regression, time-series

I have time series, for example, gdp and unemployment(`unemp`), freq= 4.

What if I interpret it as cross-sectional data and do cross-sectional analysis instead of time series?

My task is to test how unemployment affects gdp.

Is it allowed to do that kind of analysis?

Do the coefficients in the model `lm(gdp~unemp)` have an economic explanation?

Comment: If somebody gives you two vectors of numbers and tells you to run a regression of the one on the other, the technical implementation will be exactly the same - after all, this somebody did not even tell what these vectors of numbers represent. The issue is that we know by accumulated experience that time series data, especially economic data, tend to exhibit autocorrelation. This you will ignore, fatally, by treating them as cross-sectional. And if you tell your software to treat the data as c-s, most likely it won't be able to implement autocorrelation diagnostics or estimation later.

Comment: Ok. Let's get into this example. If I run the regression lm(gdp~unemp). F statistis of the model is OK, also bptest shows homoscedasticity and dwtest shows that autocorrelation=0. Does this regresion is appropriate?

Comment: You can do this but it won't mean the same scientifically or practically or (in your case) economically. Here is a simple analogy. Suppose you have data on your height and weight as a double time series. Now model that. Do you think that will capture the cross-sectional relationship between height and weight across _any_ population of people?

Answer (score 1):

The major difference between time series data and cross-section data is that the former focuses on results gained over an extended period of time, often within a small area, whilst the latter focuses on the information received from surveys and opinions at a particular time, in various locations, depending on the information sought. Moreover, gdp in one time lag is likely to be dependent on the next time lag and so on. In a cross sectional point of view, you ignore this correlation. For your problem, I guess you will be trying to see how gdp is being affected by employment over time so that you can also estimate the future scenario.